# Getting System.IO.IOException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working with the driving knowledge test program which consist of the multiple choice questions. I am having **System.IO.IOException** while trying to save the questions in the database file. Few hours earlier the same code was working  fine but now it started to show the issue. The error is also mentioning that it cannot access the file and the file is being used by the another process. I also have added the picture to show the  error that i faced

**AddQuestions.vb**

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Questions
    ' Holds question number of question currently being updating or deleting.
    Dim currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo As Integer
    Private Sub QuestionForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TXTQuestionNo.Enabled = False
        TXTQuestionNo.Text = gloTestQuestions.Count + 1
        Fill_Grid()
    End Sub

    ' Insert a new question in array list.
    Private Sub BTNAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNAdd.Click
        Dim question As Trivia_Data
        question.intQuestionNo = TXTQuestionNo.Text
        question.StrQuestion = TXTQuestion.Text
        question.StrAnswer1 = TXTAnswer1.Text
        question.StrAnswer2 = TXTAnswer2.Text
        question.StrAnswer3 = TXTAnswer3.Text
        question.StrAnswer4 = TXTAnswer4.Text
        question.intCorrectAnswer = Integer.Parse(TXTAnswer5.Text)
        gloTestQuestions.Add(question)
        Fill_Grid()
        MessageBox.Show("Question inserted successfully....")
        ClearText()
    End Sub

    ' Clears all text boxes for next question and displays possible question for it.
    Private Sub ClearText()
        TXTAnswer1.Clear()
        TXTAnswer2.Clear()
        TXTAnswer3.Clear()
        TXTAnswer4.Clear()
        TXTAnswer5.Clear()
        TXTQuestion.Clear()
        TXTQuestionNo.Clear()
        TXTQuestionNo.Text = gloTestQuestions.Count + 1
    End Sub

    ' Fills data grid view controls with available questions in a system.
    Private Sub Fill_Grid()
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("Question Number")
        dt.Columns.Add("Question")
        dt.Columns.Add("Answer1")
        dt.Columns.Add("Answer2")
        dt.Columns.Add("Answer3")
        dt.Columns.Add("Answer4")
        dt.Columns.Add("CorrectAnswer")
        Dim question As Trivia_Data
        For j = 0 To gloTestQuestions.Count - 1
            dt.Rows.Add()
            question = CType(gloTestQuestions(j), Trivia_Data)
            dt.Rows(j)("Question Number") = question.intQuestionNo.ToString()
            dt.Rows(j)("Question") = question.StrQuestion
            dt.Rows(j)("Answer1") = question.StrAnswer1
            dt.Rows(j)("Answer2") = question.StrAnswer2
            dt.Rows(j)("Answer3") = question.StrAnswer3
            dt.Rows(j)("Answer4") = question.StrAnswer4
            dt.Rows(j)("CorrectAnswer") = question.intCorrectAnswer
        Next
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub


    ' Searchs a question by user supplied question number using binary search technique. 
    Private Sub BTNFind_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNFind.Click
        Dim totalAddedQuestion As Integer = gloTestQuestions.Count
        Dim questionNo = InputBox("Enter the question number that you want to search:")
        If questionNo > gloTestQuestions.Count Or questionNo = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Question doesn't exist..........")
            ClearText()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim compare As New ArrayListIntegerComparere
            gloTestQuestions.Sort(compare)
            Fill_Grid()
            Dim max As Integer
            Dim min As Integer
            Dim mid As Integer
            min = 0
            max = totalAddedQuestion - 1
            While (max >= min)
                mid = (min + max) / 2
                Dim question As Trivia_Data = CType(gloTestQuestions(mid), Trivia_Data)
                If question.intQuestionNo < questionNo Then
                    min = mid + 1
                ElseIf question.intQuestionNo > questionNo Then
                    max = mid - 1
                Else
                    TXTAnswer1.Text = question.StrAnswer1
                    TXTAnswer2.Text = question.StrAnswer2
                    TXTAnswer3.Text = question.StrAnswer3
                    TXTAnswer4.Text = question.StrAnswer4
                    TXTAnswer5.Text = question.intCorrectAnswer
                    TXTQuestion.Text = question.StrQuestion
                    TXTQuestionNo.Text = question.intQuestionNo
                    currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo = mid
                    MessageBox.Show("Question found............")
                    BTNUpdate.Enabled = True
                    BTNDelete.Enabled = True

                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End While
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Question doesn't exist.................")
        ClearText()
    End Sub

    ' Saves questions in binary file and closes the file after writing operations.
    Private Sub BTNSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNSave.Click
        Dim file As New FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\Question.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim fileWrite As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(file)
        Dim question As Trivia_Data
        For i = 0 To gloTestQuestions.Count - 1
            question = CType(gloTestQuestions(i), Trivia_Data)
            fileWrite.Write(Convert.ToInt16(question.intQuestionNo))
            fileWrite.Write(question.StrQuestion)
            fileWrite.Write(question.StrAnswer1)
            fileWrite.Write(question.StrAnswer2)
            fileWrite.Write(question.StrAnswer3)
            fileWrite.Write(question.StrAnswer4)
            fileWrite.Write(Convert.ToInt16(question.intCorrectAnswer))
        Next
        fileWrite.Close()
        file.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Questions saved in file successfully..........")
    End Sub

    ' Updates exisitng question as per newly provided values.
    Private Sub BTNUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNUpdate.Click
        Dim question As Trivia_Data = CType(gloTestQuestions(currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo), Trivia_Data)
        question.StrAnswer1 = TXTAnswer1.Text
        question.StrAnswer2 = TXTAnswer2.Text
        question.StrAnswer3 = TXTAnswer3.Text
        question.StrAnswer4 = TXTAnswer4.Text
        question.intCorrectAnswer = Integer.Parse(TXTAnswer5.Text)
        question.StrQuestion = TXTQuestion.Text
        gloTestQuestions(currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo) = question
        MessageBox.Show("Question updated successfully...................")
        BTNUpdate.Enabled = False
        BTNDelete.Enabled = False
        ClearText()
        Fill_Grid()
    End Sub

    ' Deletes a current question from the arraylist.
    Private Sub BTNDelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNDelete.Click
        gloTestQuestions.RemoveAt(currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo)
        Fill_Grid()
        ClearText()
        MessageBox.Show("Question removed successfully.....")
        BTNDelete.Enabled = False
        BTNUpdate.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    ' Closes the Question form
    Private Sub BTNClose_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: Probably it is your own process that keeps the file. Just calling Close is not enough, you should dispose the streams. Look at how the Using Statemen could help you here

Comment: Might you have opened `Question.dat` is some other program that could have a lock on the file?

Comment: Think about accepting one of the answers and if these did not satisfy you please stay in the loop and indicate what you are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you encounter any exceptions during testing which may have caused the file not being correctly closed (`file.close()`) by your own application?

Do you have the file (`Question.dat`) open in another program?

Does an instance of your application still run and keeps the file open?

When dealing with this sort of operations it is better to rewrite your code something like this :

**EDIT** VB .NET (pseudo code)

```
Try
  Using file As New File
    ' your code...
  End Using
Catch exception As Exception
  ' log and/or show to user...
Finally
  ' your code...
  file.Close()
End Try
```

Original C# code

```
try{
  // If the file class implements IDisposable
  using(File file = new file()){
    // your code...
    ...
  }
}
catch(Exception ex){
  // log and/or show to user 
}
finally{
  file.close();
}
```

It is hard to say what process/application has the file in use or locked so for now I should say, **close and reopen Visual Studio** or even worse **restart Windows**.

Comment: I know but VB is also capable of try/catch/finally and using?

Comment: Sure, and I suppose that you are capable to write the answer in the language requested.

Comment: @Steve gave it my best shot (for what I could remember). Thanks for insisting ;)

Comment: I think the `Finally` block is superfluous as the `Using` block should already close the file when it goes out of scope.  I'd also recommend against catching `Exception`, for file I/O, it would make more sense to catch `IOException` and one or two security-related exceptions.